# Is the Cayley-Menger determinant of five points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, determinant

My understanding is that it should be zero. For example, see section 2.1 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.0349.pdf). However, when I try it out by randomly selecting coordinates for the five points and calculating the Cayley-Menger determinant in MATLAB it isn't zero.

Can someone explain this for me? Does this only hold under certain conditions? Or have I misunderstood the whole thing?

These are the points I tried:

P1 : (10, 32, 8)

P2 : (12, 1, 68)

P3 : (45, 107, 24)

P4 : (87, 36, 12)

P5 : (2, 47, 78)

The determinant value I get for the CM is: -0.1565

*EDIT:* I thought I should explain my logic a bit more. The CM determinants give a relationship for the volume of a simplex as well. If I had four points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ the volume of the tetrahedron would be zero if all four points were on a plane (essentially meaning that they are embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$). So a generalization would be that if $n$ points are to be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n-2}$ their CM determinant should be zero. This is how I concluded that the CM of five points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ should be zero. The thing is I even try the CM determinant for four coplanar points and I still don't get an absolute zero for the CM determinant (I get something near 1e-5).

*EDIT2:* I can't seem to get the symbolic solver in Matlab to give me a zero for these Cayley-Menger determinants either, but Wolfram-Alpha does.

Comment: I'd be more worried by the fact that a determinant of integer matrix turns out non-integer.

Comment: The determinant should be zero. I haven't installed Matlab on my machine, but Octave also gives a nonzero determinant. However, if we perform a QR factorisation, Octave will correctly return an $R$ that has a zero diagonal entry. So, the determinant algorithms in Matlab and Octave may be prone to badly conditioned matrices.

Comment: Try Mathematica or Maple or some other "symbolic math" program, instead. It looks like you're getting numerical round-off errors, which won't happen in those sorts of programs.

Comment: I dont understand : you give two figures for the determinant: first near $10^{-5}$  then near $10^{-1}$ @user1551 it is very dubious that the determinant algorithm of Matlab, for a $6 \times 6$ matrix, even badly conditionned, gives -0.1565 instead of 0

Comment: @bubba I just tried it online using Wolfram Alpha. It will give a zero for a 2D flat case (higher dimensions exceed permitted runtime: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=det(%7B%7B+0,+965,+6850,+5945,+1+%7D,%7B+965,+0,+12325,+6850,+1+%7D,%7B+6850,+12325,+0,+6805,1+%7D,%7B+5945,+6850,+6805,+0,1%7D,%7B1,1,1,1,0%7D%7D)

Comment: @JeanMarie yeah I guess my edit made things more confusing. I got $10^-5$ when I looked at a problem of four points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (instead of 5 points in $\mathbb{R}^3$). The points for that one were basically the first four points in my post with their 3rd coordinate dropped.

Comment: @JeanMarie Why not? The condition number is not a property of the matrix's dimension. According to Matlab's doc., it uses LU (actually PLU) decomposition to calculate the determinant. Now I don't have Matlab on my machine, but using Octave, $U$ has five nonzero diagonal entries and one zero entry. The product of the five nonzero entries is about $-1.7\times10^{15}$, while the zero entry is calculated as 5 times the machine epsilon. So Octave evaluates the modulus of the determinant as $1.7\times10^{15}\times5\times2^{-52}=1.8873$. I guess Matlab's calculation is more or less the same.

Comment: @user1551  You have convinced me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinant in question is clearly zero from a geometric point of view, but we may also give a formal proof. Put the five row vectors together to form a matrix $P$. Let $d$ be the diagonal of $PP^T$ and let $e=(1,1,1,1,1)^T\in\mathbb R^5$. Then the matrix for which we want to calculate the determinant is
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&e^T\\ e&de^T+ed^T-2PP^T}.
$$
The rank of $P^T$ is at most 3. Hence there exists a nonzero vector $x$ such that $e^Tx=P^Tx=0$. It follows that $A\pmatrix{-d^Tx\\ x}=0$, i.e. $A$ is singular.

Comment: I don't understand how you got $-d^T x$ in there though. Also, what would be a simple way to find such a $x$ vector? Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: @Hadi Any nonzero vector in the null space of $M=\pmatrix{e^T\\ P^T}$ can serve as $x$. As $M$ is $4\times5$, it has a nontrivial null space. Using Matlab, you may call `null(M)` to find a solution $x$. And if $A\pmatrix{\ast\\ x}=0$ with $e^Tx=P^Tx=0$, the asterisk must be equal to $-d^Tx$.